# How to bind `this` to reduce?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple reducer, how do I bind `this` from outside to use that inside the reducer `this.teacherInstance`?

```
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce(function (teacherIdArr, teacher) {
  if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
     teacherIdArr.push(this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(teacher.teacherId));
  }
  return teacherIdArr;
}, []);
```

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function `=>` instead of the `function` keyword?

Comment: Bind it to the function by using `.bind(this)` after the function. Or use a `var self = this;` outside of the reduce loop and use `self.teachInstance`. Or use an arrow function. Or alternatively, turn the logic around and use `.map()`, which supports a `this` argument as the second parameter and filter out the duplicates after. You could also make the reduction function a method of `this` so you can use `this.plans.reduce( this.findTeacherModels );` or something.

Comment: @OPV see this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Comment: are you sure, that `this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById` returns a single id? which is possible to use with `indexOf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using **explicit binding** with  `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce(function (teacherIdArr, teacher) {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
      teacherIdArr.push(this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(teacher.teacherId));
   }
   return teacherIdArr;
}.bind(this), []);
```

Using a **closure/reference**:

```
const self = this;
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce(function (teacherIdArr, teacher) {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
      teacherIdArr.push(self.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(teacher.teacherId));
   }
   return teacherIdArr;
}, []);
```

Using an **ES6 arrow function** that doesn't have a `this` of its own, preserving the "outer" this:

```
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce((teacherIdArr, teacher) => {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
      teacherIdArr.push(this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(teacher.teacherId));
   }
   return teacherIdArr;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as they work in `lexical scope`, so `this` is determined depending on "where" it is written:

```
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce((teacherIdArr, teacher) => {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
        teacherIdArr.push(this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(
          teacher.teacherId));
   }
       return teacherIdArr;
}, []);
```

Also have a look here: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `arrow functions` you can simply use the `bind` method with the anonymous function like this:

```
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce(function (teacherIdArr, teacher) {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
        teacherIdArr.push(this.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(
          teacher.teacherId));
   }
       return teacherIdArr;
}.bind(this), []);
```

Another approach would be to store `this` in another variable and use the lexical scope:

```
var that = this;
this.teachersDropMenu = this.plans.reduce(function (teacherIdArr, teacher) {
   if (teacherIdArr.indexOf(teacher.teacherId) == -1) {
        teacherIdArr.push(that.teacherInstance.getTeacherModelById(
          teacher.teacherId));
   }
       return teacherIdArr;
}, []);
```

Both approaches are fine.